# Duplex communication with WCF without CallbackContract

Tags: .net, wcf, named-pipes, duplex, inter-process-communicat

What is good practice using WCF for the following scenario?

Basic description

There are several modules (programs) which will provide a WCF Service. Each application can start more than one time. The normal case is that this applications are started from a kind of management console but they can also be started manually.

WCF Setup

I am using currently NetNamedPipeBinding. A ServiceHost with the address "net.pipe://localhost" and endpoints with the program name as relative address. So to access the service I would use "net.pipe://localhost/module1" for instance.

My questions

1. How can I prevent getting an AddressAlreadyInUseException when starting another instance of the same module? My idea was to use an id for each instance. But then i can't keep track of them. (f.e. how would module2 know which instance of module1 is available if the first instance is already closed). Another idea would be to use some kind of global module which will handle the instances. If I would decide just to let one instance register the service and all others will fail I will have the same problem.
2. How can a module report to the management application that it is finished with all initialization? As far as I understand a CallbackContract can only be used to call callbacks during a Method call of the ServiceContract. So do I have to start a service on the management application itself? I thought of the management application as client not a server because it will not be available all the time.